# PIN invisibility in android

Tags: security, lock-screens

I am using PIN security for unlocking the phone. When i type the PIN, a blue highlight comes to the pressed digit. How can i hide it? I am in Note 2 rooted with stock rom.

Comment: How about unchecking Visible Passwords from Settings > Location and Security?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no such function on Android. There is something similar when using a pattern to unlock your phone. Another solution would be third party software.
Also check this article on Lifehacker for much more tips on improving your phones' security
http://lifehacker.com/three-ways-to-improve-your-androids-lock-screen-securi-1293317441