# Lollipop PIN unlock - possible to hide large button feedback on screen?

Tags: lock-screens, 5.0-lollipop

The PIN unlock screen in Android 5.0/Lollipop displays a very large animated circle under each number that you press (I'm using a Nexus 5). Is there any way to disable that?  It seems like it would be very easy for someone to look over your shoulder and observe your PIN, much more so than the PIN unlock screen in KitKat.

I'll readily point out that this may be considered a duplicate of [this question regarding Android 4.4](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69348/pin-invisibility-in-android), though the PIN unlock screen differs enough in 5.0 that I thought it worth asking.